# Query optimization mysql for nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I am not able to figure out how to optimize this query, please note that t_flowhistory table has ~16500 rows and the following query just does not execute, however the same query works just fine when fired on a smaller database. Is there any way I can optimize this query?

`SELECT 
    t_flowhistory.a_productid, 
    t_flowhistory.a_torole, 
    t_product.a_reference, 
    t_flowhistory.a_assigneddate 
FROM 
    ((select * from t_flowhistory WHERE a_flowhistoryid in 
        (SELECT max(a_flowhistoryid) FROM t_flowhistory 
         GROUP by a_productid)) as t_flowhistory) 
INNER JOIN t_product ON t_product.a_productid = t_flowhistory.a_productid 
WHERE 
    (t_flowhistory.a_status like 'Assigned' or t_flowhistory.a_status like 'rejected') 
    and t_flowhistory.a_isresolved = '1' 
    and t_product.a_active = 0 
    and t_product.a_ispublished=0 
    and t_flowhistory.a_torole = 2 
ORDER BY t_flowhistory.a_assigneddate desc`

table structure for t_flowhistory:

Column  Type    Null default
a_flowhistoryid (Primary)   bigint(20)  No
a_productid bigint(20)  Yes     NULL
a_fromuserid    int(10) Yes     NULL
a_fromrole  int(10) Yes     NULL
a_torole    int(10) Yes     NULL
a_status    enum('Assigned', 'Moved', 'Completed', 'Rejected')  Yes     Assigned
a_isresolved    enum('0', '1')  Yes     1
a_reasonid  int(10) Yes     NULL
a_remarks   varchar(250)    Yes     NULL
a_assigneddate  datetime    Yes     NULL

table structure for t_products

Column  Type    Null default
a_productid (Primary)   int(11) No
a_reference varchar(42) Yes     NULL
a_price decimal(20,6)   Yes     0.000000
a_defaultcategoryid int(10) Yes     0
a_sequence  int(10) Yes     100000
a_wholesaleprice    decimal(20,6)   Yes     0.000000
a_linkrewrite   varchar(128)    Yes     NULL
a_metatitle varchar(128)    Yes     NULL
a_metakeywords  varchar(255)    Yes     NULL
a_metadescription   varchar(255)    Yes     NULL
a_ispublished   tinyint(1)  No  0
a_active    tinyint(1)  Yes     1
a_createddate   datetime    Yes     NULL
a_createdby int(11) Yes     NULL
a_modifieddate  datetime    Yes     NULL
a_modifiedby    int(11) Yes     NULL

Comment: Table definitions for the 2 tables would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query may be optimize

```
SELECT 
    t_flowhistory.a_productid, 
    t_flowhistory.a_torole, 
    t_product.a_reference, 
    t_flowhistory.a_assigneddate 
FROM t_flowhistory 
join (SELECT max(a_flowhistoryid) as a_flowhistoryid FROM t_flowhistory 
         GROUP by a_productid) a on a.a_flowhistoryid=t_flowhistory.a_flowhistoryid     
INNER JOIN t_product ON t_product.a_productid = t_flowhistory.a_productid 
WHERE 
    (t_flowhistory.a_status like 'Assigned' or t_flowhistory.a_status like 'rejected') 
    and t_flowhistory.a_isresolved = '1' 
    and t_product.a_active = 0 
    and t_product.a_ispublished=0 
    and t_flowhistory.a_torole = 2 
ORDER BY t_flowhistory.a_assigneddate desc
```

Comment: You removed a whole subquery dude, I need the columns returned by that subquery.

Comment: From t_flowhistory as table to return all columns. i Remove subquery to specify 'in'. And add extra join  look that query

Comment: I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.a_flowhistoryid' in 'on clause'

Comment: Ok add alias name to this query check it now

Comment: yeah it's running, but seems to take too long...loading.

Comment: Add some indexes `ALTER TABLE t_flowhistory add KEY(a_status ,a_isresolved ,a_torole,a_assigneddate  );` and `ALTER TABLE t_product ADD KEY(a_active ,a_ispublished)` Also replace LIKE with `=`